# Why import Upload from 'gcs-browser-upload' is failing?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpacker

I'm trying to import `https://github.com/QubitProducts/gcs-browser-upload` in a project, but it's failing with:

`"export 'default' (imported as 'Upload') was not found in 'gcs-browser-upload'`

I'm using the npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcs-browser-upload

webpacker: 4.39.1

Comment: Hi, try installing babel then converting it to ES2015, then webpack it. Let me know if this fixes it! Here's the link to babel https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2015/.

Comment: @Ameer, I'm using rails webpacker and it already ships with @babel/preset-env: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/es6.md